# Jenkins pipeline job gets triggered as anonymous but not as an user/Admin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Jenkins Pipeline job doesn't trigger pipeline job using jenkins cli. When i run jenkins as anaonymous this works, but when i create a user/admin it fails.

I have a job A which has parameters and passes the same to Pipeline Job. This is a Master-slave setup. This is how i run:

```
sudo java -jar /home/user/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL build pipeline_job -p parameter_Name="$parameter_Name" -p parameter_Name2="$parameter2_Name"
```

1.) I tried using options, "-auth" , "-username -password" but doesn't work.

errors:
No such command: -auth
No such command: -ssh

2.) Another option is paste the public key in  SSH section http://jenkin_url/me/configure , but still it fails

error:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid PEM structure, '-----BEGIN...' missing
```

Is there i am missing anything ?

Comment: This is something related to this issue - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12543

but not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution,

1.) used SSH CLI.

In my case i was using master-slave environment, connection was made using SSH keys vice-versa. In order to trigger the build using Jenkins CLI, place the SSH keys both public & private and place them in http://jenkinsURL/user/username/configure

Here username= the one used to connect the nodes.

Trigger the job as below:

```
java -jar /home/username/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa build JOBNAME
```

**Note:** This is one way but cloudbees doesn't encourage this approach.

2.) There is new approach i.e., using API token authentication.

- Go to http://jenkinsURL/user/username/configure
- Copy the API token
- trigger the build as below:

  java -jar /home/username/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth username:apitoken /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa build JOBNAME

**Note:** For using API token option, download the latest jar file

Comment: This is in general, not specific to pipeline. In general if user management is not properly set then you will not be able to trigger and job using Jenkins cli